# using multiple sprite sheets for same object AndEnginge

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine, sprite, sprite-sheet

I have multiple sprite sheets for my object(Parrot) like eating, moving left to right, right to left and much more. I am using AndEngine gles2.0. How should I implement it? every time I have to use different sprite sheet, detach previous one and on same location add new one. This is going to be hectic!

Anyone here who already implemented this kind of scenario? If I use single sprite sheet for every animation it size will increase and it will throw a exception of out of memory!

Comment: did you manage to solve this? im currently in the same situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my code to perform animations of different sprite sheets.

```
public void performEatingAnimation(Bird b) {
    float x = b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().getX();
    float y = b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().getY();
    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().setVisible(false);

    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().detachSelf();
    b.setSelectedAnimatedsprite(b.getEatingAnimatedsprite());

    attachObjectWithNewPosition(b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite(), x, y);
    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().animate(60, 2);

}

public void performWalkAnimation(Bird b) {
    float x = b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().getX();
    float y = b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().getY();
    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().setVisible(false);

    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().detachSelf();
    b.setSelectedAnimatedsprite(b.getWalkingAnimatedsprite());

    attachObjectWithNewPosition(b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite(), x, y);
    b.getSelectedAnimatedsprite().animate(60, 0)
 }
```

And here is my setSelected method to perform a deepCopy of AnimatedSprite.

```
public void setSelectedAnimatedsprite(AnimatedSprite selectedAnimatedsprite) {
    AnimatedSprite sprite = new AnimatedSprite(
            selectedAnimatedsprite.getX(), selectedAnimatedsprite.getY(),
            selectedAnimatedsprite.getTiledTextureRegion().deepCopy(),
            selectedAnimatedsprite.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    this.selectedAnimatedsprite = sprite;
}
```

I have to deepCopy the selected sprite because if I don't do that it will pass the reference and setVisible(false) and detach will happen on WalkingAnimatedSprite and EatingAnimatedSprite which I don't want in anycase